# VirtualBox Guest OS network setup is blocking Host OS network access

Tags: networking, windows-10, virtualbox, virtual-machine, centos-7

I reinstalled a different version of VirtualBox on my Win10 Host system. The Guest CentOS system and the Host were both able to communicate seamlessly with the Internet before my upgrade. I had configured the network setting of the Guest system to use NAT. Now, after the upgrade, my Host system is blocked from access to the Internet, but only within the local Windows 10 account. Troubleshooting seems to indicate that the VB network adapter is interfering the local account connect to the Internet.

I had this problem before with Win7 Host and RHEL6 Guest, and I was never able to resolve the problem. I finally had to create another local account on the Win7 system and move/copy all my files and configuration settings to be able to work normally again.

Does anyone have suggestions as to what is potentially causing this problem, or how to fix it.

Comment: If you upgraded VirtualBox for this to happen, you could uninstall it using perhaps [Revo Uninstaller Freeware](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo-uninstaller-free-download/) and reinstall. After the uninstall, ensure that all its network adapters were truly deleted and get rid of any left-overs.

Comment: Oh, I hadn't thought about the VBox network adapter being a left-over from the previous install. I'll try deleting that, and see if the local account can see the Internet again with its normal network connection.

Answer (score 0):

From my (not so recent) experience with VB, the best network setting was bridging the virtual NIC, so that your guest machine became a subnet of your home/work network in its own right. That way, you could reach your guest from outside your home/workplace too, provided your modem allowed port forwarding.

Try to stop your guest, change network settings on it from NAT to bridge and see how it goes. You can't do that if the guest machine is suspended, so you'll have to halt CentOS.

I know it's a pain in the rear, given the time it takes for a cold boot, but that's the only to test it.

Comment: I could try that, to fix the network issue. However, my workflow has my Guest OS piggy-backing a VPN connection from the Host OS. I would likely need to switch back to NAT setting for the Guest OS, because I don't know enough about networking to know, but I don't think I can "tunnel" into the VPN from another part of my subnet. Plus, I'm definitely not interested in setting up the Guest as a target from outside of LAN.

Comment: For the last part of your comment, that's easy: you won't. You have to enable port forwarding in your router for the specific IP of the guest in order for it to be visible from outside your LAN. For the rest, it's up to you. You could also install a VPN client on guest, and use it separately from the one you use on the host. Last time I played with VB, I had Windscribe on the host AND the guest, using two separate free accounts, and that worked for me. Both the host and guest were Windows OSes, though. There is a version of Windscribe for Linux.